# Get-Service issue with powershell

Tags: powershell

For some reason, when I run `Get-Service` in powershell, it throws an error. If I run `Set-Service` first however, `Get-Service` will work until I open powershell again. I can't seem to find this issue anywhere online. Has anyone experienced this and if so, is there a solution?

> Error: "Program 'Get-Service' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1"

[image: PowerShell Issue]

Comment: What is the name of the service you are providing to Set-Service?

Comment: What does `(Get-Command Get-Service).Source` return?

Comment: @EylM I didn't provide anything after Set-Service. It then prompts for the name and I just press enter. After that, Get-Service starts working.

Comment: @sodawillow For some reason, it returns "C:\Windows\System32\Get-Service". After running Set-Service, it returns "Microsoft.PowerShell.Management".

Comment: Does your `C:\Windows\System32` folder contain a `Get-Service` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Remove file `C:\Windows\System32\Get-Service` from your system - it shouldn't be there.

After that, `Get-Service` will start working again.

---

**PowerShell tries to open the perhaps accidentally created, extension-less  `C:\Windows\System32\Get-Service` file on your system *first*, *if you haven't imported module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` yet in the session*.**

- That PowerShell tries to open a *non-executable* file - one without a filename extension - that it locates via `$env:PATH` is in itself problematic - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63981418/45375).

The `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` module, which contains the `Get-Service` and `Set-Service` cmdlets (among other commands), is normally *imported on demand* the first time you try to execute one of its commands in a session.

<sup>Technically, since the module is located in a known location, it is subject to [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules#module-auto-loading).</sup>

However, **if the module isn't imported yet, an external program / document file of the same name located in one of the directories listed in environment variable `$env:PATH` *takes precedence*, and *it* is executed / opened by default.**

Since the file in your case was had no filename extension, the Windows shell did not know how to open it, resulting in the error message you saw (if you double-clicked the file in File Explorer, you'd get "How do you want to open this file?" dialog instead).

As a result, trying to execute a command named `Get-Service` by itself does *not* trigger import of the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` module - the external file keeps getting called.

By contrast, since the `Set-Service` cmdlet is *not* shadowed by an external file, calling *it* does implicitly import the module.

**Once the module has been imported, submitting command `Get-Service` calls the *cmdlet* rather than the external file**, because [PowerShell's regular command precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence) then kicks in, where cmdlets take precedence over external programs with the same name.

While this situational distinction makes the execution behavior hard to predict, *consistently* giving precedence to known cmdlets, irrespective of whether their module happens to have been imported into the current session yet or not, is not an option for *performance reasons*: see the discussion in since-closed [GitHub issue #10853](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10853).

---

**To unambiguously invoke a command from a given module, prefix the command name with the module name followed by `\`**:

That is, even without the module imported, you could have invoked the `Get-Service` cmdlet as follows:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-Service
```