# Command "docker" not recognized in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, docker

I am using Windows Powershell (on windows 10). I am also using the latest version 2.3.0.5 of docker desktop. When I type "docker version" in powershell the command is not recognized. The error message reads "Der angegebenen Datei ist keine Anwendung zugeordnet." (English: No application is assigned to the specified file). When I instead include the file extension and type "docker.exe version" the command can be executed. The interesting thing is that "docker version" works in a cmd window, but for some reason not in powershell. The extension ".exe" is contained in the windows environment variable PATHEXT.

What could be the reason that it doesn't work in powershell?

PS: I had an old version of docker installed before. There everything worked fine. Then I updated to the newest version. After that I couldn't use my existing docker containers anymore. So I uninstalled the old version and installed version 2.3.0.5. Since then I have this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

- Run `Get-Command -All docker | ForEach-Object Path`
- Among the file paths returned, *remove those that do not end in `*.exe`* (use [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)).

---

The likeliest explanation is that, in **one of the directories in your system's path (`$env:PATH`) that comes *before* the one in which `docker.exe` is located, contains *another* file whose *base name* is `docker`**:

- **Either**: It is **an *extension-less* file literally and fully named `docker`** [*This is what it the problem turned out to be*] .

  - PowerShell unexpectedly tries to execute this extension-less file, because it considers it executable, despite - by definition - not having an extension designated as executable via the `PATHEXT` environment variable (`$env:PATHEXT`).<sup>[1]</sup>

    - This would explain `cmd.exe`'s different behavior, because it sensibly never considers an extension-less file executable.
  - Presumably, the uninstallation of the old Docker version removed the original `docker.exe`, but left an extension-less `docker` file in the same directory behind (possibly a *Unix* shell script).
- **Or**: It *does* have an extension (other than `*.exe`), which:

  - refers to a file that isn't *directly* executable and needs an *interpreter* - a separate executable - in order to be executed
  - *and* that extension is listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable
  - *and* the association between the filename extension (e.g., `.py`) and the (information about the) associated interpreter is (now) missing, possibly as a result of having uninstalled the older Docker version.

---

<sup>[1] In fact, **PowerShell unexpectedly considers *any* filename extension executable** - see [GitHub issue #12632](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12632).

However, **for those extensions *not* listed in `PATHEXT`, execution via the path only works if you *include* the filename extension in a file-name-only call** (e.g., executing `file.txt` opens a file by that name located in the first folder in the path that has such a file in the associated editor). With an extension-*less* file, there is obviously no extension to include, which is why confusion with an `*.exe` file of the same base name is possible (unless you invoke *with* `.exe`); if both such files reside in the *same* directory in the path, the `*.exe` file takes precedence, but if the extension-less file is in a different directory listed *earlier* in the path, *it* takes precedence.</sup>

Comment: Thank you mklement. Finally docker commands work again in powershell, so that I don't have to add the extension ".exe". There were two paths ending with docker but without extension ".exe" that I had to remove with Remove-Item.

Answer (score 0):

Quick addition to  mklement0's answer:

The exact command for removing a path is: **Remove-Item -Path "C:\your_path\here"**