# ionic can not run in powershell,but work in cmd

Tags: powershell, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfyZL.png)i install ionic in "command prompt" windows,  it can normally run in "command prompt" windows, but it can not run in power shell and it pop up one windows to show the pic's error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyA7h.png)

[image]

Comment: What does `Get-Command ionic` show you?

Comment: it is possible the cmd shell has environment variables set correctly and powershell does not.

Comment: I suspect it is the same problem described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63980371/45375). Replace `docker` with `ionic` in the instructions there, and see if that helps. If so, we can close your question as a duplicate.